# Async and await in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am a beginner in `JS` and while going through `async` and `await` and I came across the below example:

```
const get = async () => {
    const y = await "hello";
    console.log(y);
}

console.log("start");
get();
console.log("end");
```

**O/P**

```
start
end 
hello
```

But according to my understanding `await` blocks the execution of the current program until the `promise` is available, then why in the above example that doesn't happen? Is my understanding incorrect or some other concept is missing?

Comment: _"to my understanding `await` blocks the execution of the current program"_. That's the tricky part. It does not block the program. It blocks the surrounding function only. `get()` remains asynchronous and the rest of the program around it can still run

Comment: See [Javascript Promises curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124766/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an `async` function hits the first `await` in the function, it immediately suspends further execution of that function and then immediately returns a promise from the function.  The caller receives that promise and continues to execute.  So, the current function is suspended, but not the caller or the rest of the JS engine.

So, in your code:

```
const get=async ()=>{
    const y=await "hello"
    console.log(y)
}

console.log("start")
get()
console.log("end")
```

Here's the sequence of events:

1. Logs "start"
2. Starts to execute `get()`
3. Gets to the first `await`
4. Suspends further execution of the `get()` function
5. Returns promise from `get()`
6. Calling code continues to execute and logs "end"
7. When calling code returns back to the event loop, the `await` finishes because there was no actual promise there to wait for and the `get()` function resumes executing and it logs "hello"

So, `await` only suspends execution of the current function, causing it to immediately return a promise and the calling code then continues to execute.  Sometime later when the statement you are awaiting resolves (usually a promise) and the interpreter has returned back to the event loop, then the function will continue its execution until either the next `await` or until it gets to its return value which then becomes the resolved value of the promise it originally returned and that promise gets resolved (which your code was ignoring).

Note, `await` should generally be used with promises, not with constants.  Though it doesn't cause an error to `await` something that isn't a promise, it doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

`await` is not blocking the execution of the program, it **defers** the *continuation* of the currently executed `async` method to a microtask and continues executing the code of the `async` method caller.

When you `await` something that is not a Promise(string, number or whatever) it will automatically be wrapped in a `Promise` and that promise will be awaited.

So yes, everything works as expected in your code sample.

Answer (score -5):

First of all async/await works with promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

not with strings.

If you want your code to work, here is an example =)

```js
const helloPromise = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('hello'));

const get = async () => {
  const y = await helloPromise;
  console.log(y);
}

const main = async () => {
  console.log("start");
  await get();
  console.log("end");
}

main();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `await "string"`. This is explicitly allowed, especially for this example. This is certainly not an explanation.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it was only an example, pretty the same as on mdn, ofc u shouldnt write like this. just rewrited his code to work as he wanted it to work.

Comment: This question is asking why the output is `start`, `end` and then `hello`. It isn't asking how to "fix" the issue ;)

Comment: @NickParsons I understand, totally my bad, deserved downvotes for sure, sorry =)